# Pair with "enclosing dates" rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I've got a DataFrame with two types of tasks, say Major and Minor, performed by some agents between dates:

```
ID  | StartDate           | EndDate             | Agent    | Task
-----------------------------------------------------------------
105 | 2020-01-01 12:00:00 | 2020-01-01 12:12:35 | Marty    | Major
106 | 2020-01-01 12:04:21 | 2020-01-01 12:09:08 | Wendy    | Major
109 | 2020-01-01 12:07:03 | 2020-01-01 12:11:48 | Marty    | Minor
114 | 2020-01-01 12:14:35 | 2020-01-01 12:19:10 | Wendy    | Major
117 | 2020-01-01 12:16:22 | 2020-01-01 12:16:41 | Wendy    | Minor
120 | 2020-01-01 12:17:03 | 2020-01-01 12:18:32 | Wendy    | Minor
```

I want to know when an agent has been performing a Minor task *during* also performing a Major task (it's fine to only do a Major one with no Minor in parallel). In the example below, Minor task with ID 109 starts after Major task 105 and ends before, so it does count. If multiple Minor tasks are done during one Major task, I'm happy with just retaining the first one. Ideally, I'd like to have an extra column telling me with tasks are paired along, like that:

```
ID  | StartDate           | EndDate             | Agent    | Task  | PairedWith
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
105 | 2020-01-01 12:00:00 | 2020-01-01 12:12:35 | Marty    | Major | 109
106 | 2020-01-01 12:04:21 | 2020-01-01 12:09:08 | Wendy    | Major |
109 | 2020-01-01 12:07:03 | 2020-01-01 12:11:48 | Marty    | Minor | 105
114 | 2020-01-01 12:14:35 | 2020-01-01 12:19:10 | Wendy    | Major | 117
117 | 2020-01-01 12:16:22 | 2020-01-01 12:16:41 | Wendy    | Minor | 114
120 | 2020-01-01 12:17:03 | 2020-01-01 12:18:32 | Wendy    | Minor | 114
```

I'm looking for a method not too slow to do that. At the moment I'm looping over all rows with `itertupes` and then checking "enclosing dates and same agent" conditions, which is by far the slowest part of my analysis. Would there be a quicker way, maybe with `apply` strategy...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `shift`.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = StringIO("""ID|StartDate|EndDate|Agent|Task
105|2020-01-01 12:00:00|2020-01-01 12:12:35|Marty|Major
106|2020-01-01 12:04:21|2020-01-01 12:09:08|Wendy|Major
109|2020-01-01 12:07:03|2020-01-01 12:11:48|Marty|Minor
114|2020-01-01 12:14:35|2020-01-01 12:19:10|Wendy|Major
117|2020-01-01 12:16:22|2020-01-01 12:16:41|Wendy|Minor
120|2020-01-01 12:17:03|2020-01-01 12:18:32|Wendy|Minor""")

# read data and convert to datetime to allow comparison
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='|')
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'])
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'])

# add columns for next start and id
df['NextStart'] = df.groupby('Agent')['StartDate'].shift(-1)
df['NextID'] = df.groupby('Agent')['ID'].shift(-1)

# if DropMinor is true, then next task started within window of this task
df['DropMinor'] = df['NextStart'] <= df['EndDate']

# find NextID where DropMinor is True and converts to int
exclude_ids = [int(i) for i in df.loc[df['DropMinor'], 'NextID']]

# exclude minor tasks within window
df.loc[~df.ID.isin(exclude_ids)]
```

Comment: Using shift was a good trick, I managed to build a solution to my problem with that, thanks!